# Firestore FieldValue in Codable Struct

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

How to use 'FieldValue.increment(Int64(1))' while using Codable.

```
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
struct Message: Codable, Equatable {

    @DocumentID var documentId: String?
    @ServerTimestamp var date: Timestamp?
    //Need to assign FieldValue.increment(Int64(1))

}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail what you're trying to accomplish, and the code you're working with that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson I need to assign FieldValue type in my struct and use 'increment'.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FieldValue